# Dynamic array in spinner issue

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist, spinner, android-spinner

Scenario : I have 2 spinners with one adapter and global array. When any one select an item from one spinner then that item will delete from global array.Problem is when an item suppose select with 0 index again after deleting that item from global array and another item at acquire position with 0 index . If I will select that 0 index changed item then it will not select other than all items will select.

So can any one explain or suggest what i want to do in this scenario.

```
     List<String> spinnerArray =  new ArrayList<String>();
HashMap<String, String> index_val = new HashMap<String, String>();
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_left;
            spinnerArray.add("None");
                spinnerArray.add("Task");
                spinnerArray.add("Priority");
                spinnerArray.add("Deadline");
                spinnerArray.add("Assigned to");
                spinnerArray.add("Created by");
                spinnerArray.add("Closed by");
                spinnerArray.add("Category");
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(activity, R.layout.spinner_selected_item, noneArray);
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);

                adapter_left = new ArrayAdapter<String>(activity, R.layout.spinner_selected_item_left, spinnerArray);

                adapter_left.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
    task_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                    if(!index_val.get("1").equalsIgnoreCase("None")){
                        spinnerArray.add(index_val.get("1"));
                    }
                    current_selected_val = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                    index_val.put("1", current_selected_val);

                    if(!current_selected_val.equalsIgnoreCase("none")) {
                        spinnerArray.remove(spinnerArray.indexOf(current_selected_val));

                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

                }

            });
```

Comment: what u have tried post ur code

Comment: post your code or tell us what efforts you did

Comment: @ShrenikShah I have posted my code . Problem is when you selecting the same index which you have been previously selected then the item will not select although there value has been changed . hope you got it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible, because spinner maintains their items on behalf of index instead of actual items.

Comment: Yes, you are right . It`s not possible through spinner that you can change the the item with the same index which you were selected previously and delete from array.

Answer (score 2):

Your Array Adapter should be notify every time, when ever you modify an array list like adding, deleting or updating.

So notify your adapter.

I hope this might help you.

Comment: This should be comment @Amit

Comment: @ShrenikShah As you know my reputation is not higher than 50.
So i am not able to make a comment.

Comment: @AmitVaishnava Thanks for you suggestion . But I have already tried to notify adapter If I notified then the first item of array will automatically set and selected item has been delete.